# Jquery Form Validation

Tags: jquery

My code is for form validation.Its working good But its very lengthy,If I add extra fields means again I want to add more code right?So I want to make it simple. Can I reduce this code?Can anyone give me an idea to write the following code in a simple way?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#fromDate').click(function(){
            $(this).addClass('visited');
        });
        $('#toDate').click(function(){
            $(this).addClass('visited');
        });
});
function apply(){  
        var FirstName=$('#name').val();
        if(FirstName==""){
            $('#name').addClass("error");  
        }else{
             $('#name').removeClass("error"); 
        }

        $('#fromDate').hasClass('visited')?$("#fromDate").removeClass("error"):$("#fromDate").addClass("error");
        $('#toDate').hasClass('visited')?$("#toDate").removeClass("error"):$("#toDate").addClass("error");

}
```

```css
.error{
 border:1px solid #FF0000 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="name">
<label>From</label>
<input type="date" name="" id="fromDate">
<label >Date To</label>
<input type="date" name="" id="toDate">
<button class="send" onclick="apply()">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: use jquery form validator . much easy and have lot of options available

Comment: https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten this as much:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fromDate, #toDate').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('visited');
  });
});

function apply() {
  var FirstName = $('#name').val();
  $('#name').toggleClass("error", FirstName == "");

  $("#fromDate").toggleClass("error", !$('#fromDate').hasClass('visited'));
  $("#toDate").toggleClass("error", !$('#toDate').hasClass('visited'));

}
```

Or you can pass `this` in the function args:

```
<button class="send" onclick="apply(this)">Send</button>
```

now in the function:

```
function apply($this) {
  var $els = $this.siblings('input');
  $els.each(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("error", $(this).val() == "");
  });
}
```